# "Pending suggested edit" message is displayed on separate text-only page, instead of as inline popup

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, design, error-message

I got the below error for the first time:

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes.

Issue is not with the error message, but the bland way it was displayed. Just a blank new page with this message as text.

It should have been popup as it always is? Or it was just for me.

Comment: Got this just now: https://imgur.com/a/yNULq Only once, when clicked again, the normal notification shows up.